# Prove that if $a\neq b$ and if $(x-a)$ & $(x-b)$ divide $f(x)$, then $ (x-a)(x-b) \mid f(x)$

Tags: polynomials

> Prove that if $a\neq b$ and if $(x-a)$ & $(x-b)$ divide $f(x)$, then $(x-a)(x-b) \mid f(x)$

We know that $(x-a)\mid f(x)$ & $(x-b) \mid f(x)$, but what does this imply for polynomials and how can we go about proving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the division algorithm for polynomials, there exists some $g(x)$ and some $h(x)$ of degree at most $1$ such that

$$f(x)=g(x)(x-a)(x-b)+h(x).$$

We see, by letting $x=a$ in this relation, that $h(a)=0$. Similarly, $h(b)=0$. Since $h$ is linear with two roots, $h\equiv 0$.

Comment: "Since $h$ is linear with two roots, $h \equiv 0 $." Is this a proof by contradiction? The reasoning going something like this: since $h(x)$ has degree at most one by the polynomial division algorithm, then $h(x)$ is a linear polynomial or a constant function. If $h(x)$ is a linear polynomial, it has two distinct roots $a \neq b$ , which is impossible? Whilst the 'constant' function $h(x) = 0$ does satisfy $h(a) = 0$ and$ h(b) = 0$